# QGIS area calculation disparity in identify feature vs PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, area

I have a single polygon layer in two different CRSs. I noticed the area calculations are way off between the two CRSs. EPSG 2284 and 5070

I have attached both layers. https://file.io/LRW3NniQU4ji

The area from the identify feature method is the same ~156 square miles for both layers.

[image]

But when I run the following code snippet. The output is ~156 for EPSG:2284 but ~212 for EPSG:5070

```py
layer=iface.activeLayer()
unit_type =  QgsUnitTypes.AreaSquareMiles
d = QgsDistanceArea()
tr_cont = QgsCoordinateTransformContext()
d.setSourceCrs(layer.crs(), tr_cont)
#d.setEllipsoid(layer.crs().ellipsoidAcronym())
extent_area = d.measureArea(QgsGeometry().fromRect(layer.extent()))
area = d.convertAreaMeasurement(extent_area, unit_type)
print(area)
```

I tried both layers on the clean project. Also commenting uncommenting line `d.setEllipsoid(layer.crs().ellipsoidAcronym())` is not making any major difference.

Why are areas different?